# How can I use Javascript to get a list of all picture URLs available on a site?

Tags: javascript, url, dom

I'm curious as to how DownThemAll does this. Do they use Javascript?

How can I get a list of all of the urls in a website using Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using collections**

Links: `document.links` (href)

Images:
`document.images` (src)

**Using DOM**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')
```

Bookmarklet:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u92Ra/)

```
(function(){
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),t=[];
  for (var i=0, n=imgs.length;i<n;i++) 
    t.push('<a href="'+imgs[i].src+'"><img src="'+
                       imgs[i].src+'" width="100"></a>'); 
  if (t.length) {
    var w=window.open('','_blank'); 
    if (w) {w.document.write(t.join('&nbsp;'));w.document.close();}
    else alert('cannot pop a window');  
  }    
 })();
```

Now you can save the new page to your harddisk and there will be a dir full of images

Comment: So document.getElementsByTagName('img') returns an array?

Answer (score 2):

```
var list=[];
var a=document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0,l=a.length;i<l;i++)
{
    if (/\.(jpg|gif|png|jpeg)$/im.test(a[i].getAttribute('src')))
    {
        list.push(a[i].getAttribute('src'));
    }
}
```

This code would generate list of picture URL's which are used in `<img>`

Comment: Why bother filtering if you only get img tags?

Comment: link to php-generated images.

Comment: And they would not download? If their mime type was image/something they would also be images... Perhaps more interesting would be to filter on size

Comment: usual, you dont want to save such a pictures) or you like something like captchas) in addition, using filter is great customizable to parse images from another tags or sources