# TChromium : how to save a specific image to file?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I'm using TChromium and I need to navigate to a specific page and save a specific image of this page to a file.

I know how to navigate and extract the HTML source to get the image's address, but I don't know how to save the image to my local filesystem.

How can I do it using some TChromium method ?

I don't want to use another component (such TIdHTTP) to do it because the site requires login and the image relies on the active session.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's just an HTTP GET command

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nope because to the image shows, the user should be logged in the site. Because this and other reasons i want to use TChromium.

Comment: Please edit the question to include these extra details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From CEF forums:

> "CEF does not currently support the extraction of cached resources.
>   You can identify the request that originally returned the content by
>   overriding CefRequestHandler::OnBeforeResourceLoad() and then execute
>   the request yourself using CefWebURLRequest the retrieve and save the
>   contents."

Another approach is to add a context menu as asked here - [TChromium how to add "Save Picture" item in Context Menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645462/tchromium-how-to-add-save-picture-item-in-context-menu) and where TLama has made a code snippet:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtDlgs, IdHTTP, cefvcl, ceflib;

const
  MENU_ID_SAVE_IMAGE_AS = Ord(MENU_ID_USER_FIRST) + 1;

type
  TDownloader = class(TThread)
  private
    FURL: string;
    FFileName: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const URL, FileName: string); reintroduce;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Chromium1: TChromium;
    SavePictureDialog1: TSavePictureDialog;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Chromium1BeforeContextMenu(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
      const frame: ICefFrame; const params: ICefContextMenuParams; const model: ICefMenuModel);
    procedure Chromium1ContextMenuCommand(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
      const frame: ICefFrame; const params: ICefContextMenuParams; commandId: Integer;
      eventFlags: TCefEventFlags; out Result: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TDownloader }

constructor TDownloader.Create(const URL, FileName: string);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FURL := URL;
  FFileName := FileName;
end;

procedure TDownloader.Execute;
var
  HTTPClient: TIdHTTP;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    HTTPClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FFileName, fmCreate);
      try
        HTTPClient.Get(FURL, FileStream);
      finally
        FileStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      HTTPClient.Free;
    end;
  except
    // error handling ignored for this example
  end;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chromium1.Load('http://www.google.com/');
end;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1BeforeContextMenu(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame; const params: ICefContextMenuParams; const model: ICefMenuModel);
begin
  if (CM_TYPEFLAG_MEDIA in params.TypeFlags) and (params.MediaType = CM_MEDIATYPE_IMAGE) then
    model.AddItem(MENU_ID_SAVE_IMAGE_AS, 'Save image as...');
end;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1ContextMenuCommand(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame; const params: ICefContextMenuParams; commandId: Integer;
  eventFlags: TCefEventFlags; out Result: Boolean);
var
  SaveDialog: TSavePictureDialog;
begin
  if (commandId = MENU_ID_SAVE_IMAGE_AS) then
  begin
    SaveDialog := TSavePictureDialog.Create(nil);
    try
      // SaveDialog.FileName := <here you can extract file name from params.SourceUrl>;
      // SaveDialog.DefaultExt := <here you can extract file ext from params.SourceUrl>;
      if SaveDialog.Execute then
        TDownloader.Create(params.SourceUrl, SaveDialog.FileName);
    finally
      SaveDialog.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Another approach is to identify all the images from the page (take a look at [How can I use Javascript to get a list of all picture URLs available on a site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998683/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-get-a-list-of-all-picture-urls-available-on-a-site)) and download the image link by using `CefBrowserHost.StartDownload`.

Answer (score 0):

Add to Form1:

```
public
  var file_download_finished : boolean;


procedure TForm1.Chromium1BeforeDownload(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const downloadItem: ICefDownloadItem;
  const suggestedName: ustring; const callback: ICefBeforeDownloadCallback);
begin
  callback.Cont('FileName.jpg', false);
end;

procedure TForm1.Chromium1DownloadUpdated(Sender: TObject;
   const browser: ICefBrowser; const downloadItem: ICefDownloadItem;
   const callback: ICefDownloadItemCallback);
var i : nativeint;
begin
  if downloadItem.IsComplete then     
    file_download_finished := true
  else        
    i := downloadItem.PercentComplete;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var M: TMsg;
begin
  file_download_finished := false;

  Chromium1.Browser.Host.StartDownload('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7ffbdc105c382c0070cdd29d073725b5?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1');

  repeat // wait until download is finished
    while PeekMessage(M, 0, 0, 0, pm_Remove) do
      begin
        TranslateMessage(M);
        DispatchMessage(M);
      end;
  until file_download_finished;
end;
```